# Sql trace using Entity Framework 4.1 against SQL Server CE 4

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-ce-4

Without using an external tracer such as SQL Profiler or EF Profiler.  Is there a way of tracing the SQL for the statement below using EF 4.1 against an SQL Server CE database?

```
int count = context.Customers.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Though each supported database back end typically supplies its own tracing methods, Entity Framework actually has its own built in tracing routines, the use of which depends a bit upon whether you're using Code First or not. I refer you to the following SO question for further details:

[Entity Framework 4.1 - EFTracingProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788309/entity-framework-4-1-eftracingprovider)