# How to log SQL using entity framework 4.3 (code first) and SQL Azure database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I realize this similar question has been asked a few times, and I have tried the recommendations in those questions without success.

I am using the entity framework (4.3) and running against SQL Azure (on a federated database).  I'd like to be able to log the SQL that is being generated by the entity framework.

I've used the [Entity Profiler Framework](http://efprof.com/) and while that is helpful during development, I am not sure it would be helpful during production.

I can't use SQL Profiler as this is a SQL Azure database.

I've tried using the EFTracingProvider and following the steps in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788309/entity-framework-4-1-eftracingprovider).  Unfortunately, when I attempt to execute my first command (which is using the appropriate federation), I get an exception indicating that the "Specified method is not supported."

The code which generates the error is the following:

```
public MyContext(int tenantId) 
    : base(CreateTracingConnection("TheDb"), true)
{
    const string FederationCmdText =
        "USE FEDERATION TenantFederation(CustomerId = {0}) WITH RESET, FILTERING=ON";

    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.EnableTracing();

    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.Connection.Open();

    // This is the line which throws the exception
    this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(string.Format(FederationCmdText, tenantId));        
}
```

Here's the exception:

```
Specified method is not supported.
at EFProviderWrapperToolkit.DbConnectionWrapper.CreateDbCommand()
at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.CreateCommand()
...
```

So here are my questions:

- Is EFTracingProvider the preferred approach for logging SQL queries (globally)?
- If so, any ideas why I am getting the above exception?
- If not, is there another mechanism that will allow me to log all of the SQL generated by the Entity Framework?

Thanks for your help,
Eric

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue that I was running into was because, I believe, the EFTracingProvider does not have support for executing SQL directly.  In order to workaround that issue, one solution is the following (which I found in the Q&A from [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers))

Create the following class:

```
public class DbTracingConnection : EFTracingConnection
{
    protected override DbCommand CreateDbCommand()
    {
        return this.WrappedConnection.CreateCommand();
    }
}
```

When creating the connection, use the above class instead of the EFTracingConnection.

Comment: This seems what authors recommend as well. [Here](http://efwrappers.codeplex.com/) in "Known Problems" they say to execute store commands by `context.Connection.GetStoreConnection().CreateCommand()`. So effectively doing what you did and use the wrapped connection :)