# EF generating "Specified method is not supported" error in SqlQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am currently using Entity Framework 5
I've tried to code the following:

```
var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<Entity>("SELECT * FROM ref.Entity");
```

But I get the following error:

```
Specified method is not supported.
```

Can anyone show me a resolution to this issue?

stack trace

> "at EFProviderWrapperToolkit.DbConnectionWrapper.CreateDbCommand()\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.CreateCommand()\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateStoreCommand(String commandText, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery[TElement](String sql, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQueryAsIEnumerable[TElement](String sql, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery(Type elementType, String sql, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlNonSetQuery.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlQuery`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()"

Comment: ref will be undefined ... SQL wont know what to do with that?

Comment: don't uderstand you comment, ExecuteSqlCommand() also return System.NotSupportedException

Comment: Can you post Exception stack trace

Comment: falls EFProviderWrapperToolkit. problem solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285621/how-to-log-sql-using-entity-framework-4-3-code-first-and-sql-azure-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. I am not sure if you have the source code of EFProviderWrapperToolkit, you should get it and have a look at it. You will notice that DbConnectionWrapper, which inherits from DbConnection it overrides CreateDbCommand method but does not provide any functionality for it, instead it throws and exception.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Creates and returns a <see cref="T:System.Data.Common.DbCommand"/> object associated with the current connection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A <see cref="T:System.Data.Common.DbCommand"/> object.
        /// </returns>
        protected override DbCommand CreateDbCommand()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is mentioned in "Known Problems" section on codeplex "Community Entity Framework Provider Wrappers" [site](http://efwrappers.codeplex.com/). Citing:

> Directly executing store commands using methods such as ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand or ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery is not supported. You may, however, create a DbCommand from the database connection using code such as this:
>
> ```
>     using EFProviderWrapperToolkit;
>     ...
>     context.Connection.GetStoreConnection().CreateCommand()
> ```