# How do I log all SQL statements in ObjectContext

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to do a log of all SQL statements done. I'm using EF5 and this is my context constructor

```
public partial class Entities : ObjectContext
{
    public const string ConnectionString = "name=Entities";
    public const string ContainerName = "Entities";

    #region Constructors

    public Entities()
        : base(ConnectionString, ContainerName)
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
```

**Update:**

This works fine for me: http://efwrappers.codeplex.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging SQL statements of Entity Framework 5 for database-first aproach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829898/logging-sql-statements-of-entity-framework-5-for-database-first-aproach)

Comment: tkz, i'll see, i think its a perfect solution for my case

Comment: It looks like the codeplex link is broken... My guess it that the same content can be found at https://ripcode.net/p/efwrappers (... even if I wasn't able to make it work with EF5 and ObjectContext)

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
```

for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Comment: then you should edit your question, which says "I'm using EF6"

Comment: do you know other way to help me? I just found for DbContext, but ObjectContext is diferent i think 'cause i cannot implement none of solutions that i found.

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev, EF Provider wrappers only work for EF 4 and 5

On the page of your link:
"This sample only applies to Entity Framework 4 and 5"

Answer (score 0):

For those coming here at this point in time. You can now easily log EF queries by configuring an interceptor in your configuration:

```
<interceptors>
  <interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="C:\Temp\LogOutput.txt"/>
    </parameters>
  </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file